# How to read pre-loaded SQLITE database using FLASK

Tags: flask

I am developing a database with a web-interface for the very first time using FLASK-SQLITE. The basic functionality is to '**search**' the database. I have a large list of tables which I have to ***preload*** in my database. I used a simple python script to load the csv file to a database:

***To create the database and bulk-load the table:***

```
import csv
import sqlite3

# Create the database
connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Create the table
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS line_info')
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE line_info (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, acc_id TEXT, EUSOL_id TEXT, acc_name TEXT, reasons TEXT, genebank TEXT);")
connection.commit()

# Load the CSV file into CSV reader
creader = csv.reader(open("line_info.csv", 'rt', encoding = 'utf-8'))

# Iterate through the CSV reader, inserting values into the database
for i in creader:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO  line_info VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)', i )


connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

So now I checked and the test.db has been created. Now I am confused as to what needs to go into my ***models.py*** incase if I have a pre-loaded database. A**lso, do I need to change anything in config.py and __init__.py?**

My **models.py**:

```
from app import db
class Line_info(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    acc_ID = db.Column(db.String)
    EUSOL_id = db.Column(db.String)
    acc_name = db.Column(db.String)
    reasons = db.Column(db.String)
    genebank = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, acc_ID,EUSOL_id,acc_name,reasons,genbank):
        self.acc_ID = acc_ID
        etc....................
```

My **config.py**

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

My **__init__.py**:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
#from flask_migrate import Migrate

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)    
#migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

Comment: I think it makes more sense instead to create Line_info instances inside the for loop ("for i in creader:") instead of the INSERT statement.

Comment: Hi, for the bulk upload, I wrote an independent python script. What you are suggesting is to do the same inside model.py ? I am new to flask and would be of great help if you could write a code snippet for me to understand. Thanks.

Comment: I created an example where you can search an sqlite db here: https://github.com/thomaxxl/safrs/blob/master/examples/demo_search.py it does use json however.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look into it . I can convert my table into json format.